# Contacts gets automatically updated

Tags: windows-live-messenger, windows-live-mail, hotmail, windows-live

A lot of my friends are using the new Windows Live Messenger 2011. So everyone only views a first name and surname.

My friends think: "I want some dots and commas in my name". So they change their surname to a dot. The problem is: This new surname is automatically updated in my Windows Live Mail. So some of my friends are now called like: `John K` or `Pete .`. And when I update their names back to the original, the information is overridden again when they update their name once again.

Question:

> How can I turn the automatic name updating off in Windows Live Mail?

I would like to have their real names instead of what they make of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Live updates your contact info automatically when your friends update their profile, which is why you're seeing this. You can override their name setting by setting a nickname for your contacts by right-clicking and clicking "Add a nickname".

Comment: Thanks, I knew about the nicknames already, but this just a workaround for the problem. Is there no way to turn it off?

Comment: Unfortunately not.